# when using a progressbar gui form how to exceed the limit max [int32] of $progressbar.Maximum

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, int64, int32

I sometimes need to back up large files. I made a program to help me in this task which displays a gui progress bar. $progressbar.Maximum is an int32 type and I can not modify it to int64.

I tried to convert it like this

[int64]$progressbar.Maximum = $weightfile

or like this

$progressbar.Maximum = [int64]$weightfile

But $progressbar.Maximum is always an int32

Here a part of my code

```
...
ForEach ($file in $namefile ) {
#[$poidsfile = [convert]::ToByte((gci -Path $file.fullname).Length)
$weightfile = (gci -Path $file.fullname).Length

$i=0
do {$i++
    $ProgressBar1.Maximum = $weightfile
    $pct = ($i/$weightfile)*100
    $TextBox1.Text = [System.Math]::Round($pct,2)
    $ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
   } until ($i -eq $weightfile)
}
Write-Host '$i ==' $i
...
```

how to change to int64 ?

Comment: Why do you need to use `int64` in your case?

Comment: because is limited by max value of int32; i need to pass out when using large files

Comment: The Maximum property on a ProgressBar object is defined as an Int32. I don't think there is a simple fix for this. Maybe you can change the units of `$weightfile` to be KB or MB like `$weightfile/1KB` and change your code a bit. No matter the number type you attempt to assign to it, it will convert to an Int32 if possible and error if not.

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are trying to accomplish? It just appears that measuring the progress of a file byte by byte is not what the ProgressBar class is used for. Typically, you'd see ProgressBar used where each Step represents an entire file rather than a byte of a file.

Comment: I'm learning about powershell. I'm trying to accomplish a progressbar file byte to byte. But it seems it can't works because step is an int32 ; and if i understand we can't change that